# Foreign key not being returned in sqlite3 db Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a model form that saves a 'note' using a few different fields like title, and creation date. The owner of the form is the user who is currently logged in. At the moment when I am logged in and enter the data into the form, the data is being saved, which I checked in sqlite3 using `select * from notes_note;`

This returns each form entry, and returns the primary key for each, but the foreign key (for the different users) is not being displayed.

I tried running `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` and `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;` but this didn't work.

Where can I next look? Not sure what code to post here as I don't know where to start looking for the problem.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Note(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    createTime = models.DateTimeField()

from django.forms import ModelForm

class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        exclude = ['owner']
```

**Saving notes in views.py dashboard function:**

```
@login_required(login_url="/notes/index/")
def dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # d dict is a copy of our request.Post because it's immutable and we need to add owner
        d = request.POST.copy()
        d.update({'owner': request.user.id})
        form = NoteForm(d)
        if not form.is_valid():
            template = loader.get_template('dashboard.html')
            context = {
                'form': form,
            }
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
        
        note = form.save(commit=False)
        note.owner = request.user
        note.save()
        return redirect("dashboard")
    else:
        template = loader.get_template('dashboard.html')
        context = {
            'form': NoteForm(),
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
```

Comment: Do you have Django models? Please show them. Also, code that you used to save the notes with the logged-in user.

Comment: Why would you pull data from db using raw queries ? foreign key are just relations, you can check for them running the python manage.py shell and query for the foreign key

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I just added the code

Comment: @Paaksing how would I query for the foreign key using manage.py?

Comment: Your code seems fine. How did you pull your data from database?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I used select * from notes_note; command.

Comment: use orm. just like `Note.objects.all()`